# Parser is reading tags not in the XML file

Tags: android, xml, parsing

So, I am trying to parse through this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ButtonDescs</key>
    <array>
        <string>See more information</string>
        <string>Talk to a sales person now</string>
        <string>Question about this vehicle?</string>
        <string>Schedule a Test Drive</string>
        <string>Get a quote for this vehicle</string>
        <string>Apply for a loan</string>
        <string>Calculate monthly payment</string>
        <string>Vehicle History Report</string>
    </array>
    <key>ButtonTitles</key>
    <array>
        <string>More Details</string>
        <string>Call Us</string>
        <string>Email Us</string>
        <string>Test Drive</string>
        <string>Get a Quote</string>
        <string>Finance Request</string>
        <string>Loan Calculators</string>
        <string>CarFax®</string>
    </array>
    <key>ButtonTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>details</string>
        <string>phone</string>
        <string>vehicle_question</string>
        <string>test_drive</string>
        <string>quote</string>
        <string>credit_form</string>
        <string>loan_calculators</string>
        <string>carfax</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the parser I am using:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(context, url));
        xpp.setInput(inputStreamReader);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                  if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("key")) {
                      xpp.next();
                      if(xpp.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("ButtonDescs"))
                          btnMembers = ButtonMembers.DESCS;
                      else if(xpp.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("ButtonTitles"))
                          btnMembers = ButtonMembers.TITLES;
                      else if(xpp.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("ButtonTypes"))
                          btnMembers = ButtonMembers.TYPES;
                  } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("array")) {
                      i = 0;
                  } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
                      if(btnMembers == ButtonMembers.DESCS) {
                          button = new InventoryDetailButton();
                          xpp.next();
                          button.setDescription(xpp.getText());
                          btnList.add(button);
                      } else if(btnMembers == ButtonMembers.TITLES) {
                          xpp.next();
                          btnList.get(i).setTitle(xpp.getText());
                      } else if(btnMembers == ButtonMembers.TYPES) {
                          xpp.next();
                          btnList.get(i).setType(xpp.getText());
                      }
                  }
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                  if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
                      i++;
                  } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("array") && btnMembers == ButtonMembers.TYPES) {
                      return btnList;
                  }
              }
              eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can copy and paste the URL directly into a browser and I will get the XML as I have pasted above. However, when the parser starts going through the tags, it is not the expected tags. I can step through the process and the `xpp` object will have names like `html`, `meta` and `script`. Once it gets to the `script` tag, the parser blows up.

Does anyone have any idea where these tags might be coming from?

Comment: have you tried to view source in your browser of the XML page you speak of?

Comment: There are a couple of PLIST parser libraries out there.  A quick Google will find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea where these tags might be coming from?

From your Web server, which is not recognizing your request and is returning a Web page, possibly with some form of error information.